# 尚活 can still work without 着?

Tags: word-choice, characters

Can this two hanzi alone "尚活" support the meaning "still alive" without this last one "着"?

And if yes, what does "着" add to the general sense? 
I mean, what's the difference between "活着" and "活"? I've seen both used in similar situations, and I found this "尚活着" written poem without a real grammatic context, so I wandered if "活" alone can't stand the meaning "alive" in an abstract text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see grammar,dictionaries,bkrs：**活**：to live
alive living （work workmanship）动
（生存; 有生命） live:
吃为了活，不要活为了吃。 Eat to live， but do not live to eat.
他们将永远活在我们心中。形
（在活的状态下） alive; living:
活老虎 a live tiger
活捉 capture alive
活字典 a walking dictionary

**着** durative aspectual particle,动态（时态）助词，表示动作还在持续,

**活着** I
[live] 度过生活
我只为科学而活着, 也只关心科学
II
(1) [alive; living]∶有生命; 非死状态
他站在死去的和活着的人们之间
(2) [surviving]∶仍然有生命, 仍然没死
我青年时期一个仍然活着的朋友
it might seem therefore that 尚活 could mean "still alive, living" cf. 尚病,年岁尚小,尚未死，but in fact 尚活 always seems to be followed by 着, web shows exceptions LOFALi爱尚活的微博_微博,尚活族

Answer (score 1):

literally,尚活 works.is it right to express *you can use it that way*

Answer (score 1):

A good way to see how a word is used is to search it in Google [news](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E5%B0%9A%E6%B4%BB%22&tbm=nws&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiO_I_qvbXiAhUGKY8KHUvdCj0Q_AUICigB&biw=1280&bih=672&dpr=1). There are examples of 尚活着:

- 復星集團是中國併購4大天團中，**尚活著**好好的唯一一家。
- 它是國家與社會，個體互動下，**尚活著**的一份證據。
- 「俄羅斯媒體錯誤報導，霍洛斯托夫斯基尚活著且在家休養。

---

There are also examples of 尚活 by itself:

- 每次我看到這一幕時，總不禁會想起來，如今尚活在藍軍裏頭的那些曾經服務於警總單位的「老伯伯老奶奶」們，真是情何以堪！
- 有關高砂義勇隊的戰歿及生還人數，以及至今究竟有多少人尚活在世上，不僅有不同說法，也還有種種猜測。
- AppWorks 創辦人林之晨提到，至今尚活耀於市場的新創團隊所有企業年營業額加總有19 億美金
- 雲南省一名孫姓黑道份子， 1998 年遭到法院判處死刑， 20 年後尚活在人世間不說，還搖身一變成為夜店大亨在外趴趴走。